# Calculate by how much a row has shifted horizontally in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, data-preprocessing

I have a dataframe where the **rows have been shifted horizontally** by an unknown amount. **Each and every row has shifted by a different amount** as shown below:

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 | Unnamed: 1 | Unnamed: 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | 34 | 24 | NaN |
| 5 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | 13 | 77 |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | 18 |

In the above dataframe, there are only **2 original columns** (**Heading 1** and **Heading 2**) but due to row shift (in rows **1** and **3**), **extra columns** (**Unnamed: 1 and Unnamed: 2**) have been created with the default name **Unnamed: 1** and **Unnamed: 2**.

Now **for each row**, I want to **calculate**:

1.) The **spill over**. Spill over is basically the amount of NaN values in extra columns(**Unnamed** columns). For example in **row 1** there is **one non NaN** value in extra columns (Unnamed: 1) and hence the **spill over is 1**. In **row 2** there are **no non NaN** values in extra columns so the **spill over is 0**. In **row 3** there are **2 non NaN** values in extra columns(Unnamed: 1 and Unnamed: 2) hence the **spill over is 2** and in **row 4** there are **1 non NaN** values in extra columns so the **spill over is 1**.

2.) The **amount of NaN values in the original columns**(**Heading 1** and **Heading 2**). For example in **row 1** amount of **Nan values in original columns are 1**, in **row 2** amount of **NaN values in original columns is 0**, in **row 3** amount of **NaN values in original columns is 2** and in **row 4** amount of **NaN values in original columns is 2**.

So basically for each row, I have to **calculate the amount of Nan values in **original** columns(**Heading 1** and **Heading 2**) and the amount of non NaN values in **extra** columns(Unnamed: 1 and Unnamed: 2).**

I can get the amount of extra columns (Unnamed:1 and so on) present in a dataframe by:

```
len(df.filter(regex=("Unnamed:.*")).columns.to_list())
```

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Updated Answer**

The logic that @mozway gave was an elegant one liner which i liked a lot but for some reason does not work always. Also it does not give the non nan values in the extra columns.

I managed to get it working in a slightly long but relatively simple to understand logic. Here goes:

```
#read the excel file
df = pd.read_excel('df.xlsx')

#subset the df into original and extra df's
extra = df.filter(regex=("Unnamed:.*"))
original = df.drop(extra, axis = 1)

#ori contains a list of count of NaN values in original columns as asked 
ori = original.isnull().sum(axis=1).tolist() #or to_dict() if you want a dict
ext = len(extra.columns) - extra.isnull().sum(axis=1)
#ext1 contains a list of count of non NaN values in the extra columns as asked
ext1 = ext.tolist() # or to_dict() if you want a dict
```

### Original comment/answer

@mozway As mentioned in the comments I am adding your code I tried to apply the logic to only a subset of dataframe:

```
extra = df.filter(regex=("Unnamed:.*"))
y = extra.isna().cummin(axis=1).sum(axis=1).clip(upper=2).tolist()
```

According to the dataframe the output should be [1, 2, 0, 1] (as there are 1 nan values in row 1, 2 in row 2 0 in row 3 and 1 in row 4) but the above code is giving output [0, 2, 0, 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummin.html) to identify the leading NAs, then [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) to count them and [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) to limit the shift to the original number of columns:

```
df.isna().cummin(axis=1).sum(axis=1).clip(upper=2)
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    0
2    2
3    2
dtype: int64
```

Intermediates:

```
df.isna()

   Heading 1  Heading 2  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2
0       True      False       False        True
1      False      False        True        True
2       True       True       False       False
3       True       True        True       False

df.isna().cummin(axis=1)

   Heading 1  Heading 2  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2
0       True      False       False       False
1      False      False       False       False
2       True       True       False       False
3       True       True        True       False

df.isna().cummin(axis=1).sum(axis=1)

0    1
1    0
2    2
3    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: What if I want to limit the shift to the last 2 extra columns i.e `Unnamed:1` and `Unnamed: 2`?

Comment: @spectre not sure I follow you

Comment: The solution you gave runs the logic only upto the first 2 columns `Heading 1` and `Heading 2` (because of `df.clip(upper=2)`) right? Now I want to run the same login for the last 2 extra columns i.e `Unnamed: 1` and `Unnamed: 2` so that I can calculate the NaN values for each row in the extra columns and not the original columns.

Comment: No, my solution counts the number of shifts and ensures the number doesn't get over the number of original columns. If you want to count the shifts on a subset, then first subset and apply the same logic

Comment: I want to apply the same solution to only the extra columns i.e the `Unnamed` ones. So I took the subset which only contains the `Unnamed:` columns. Now when I applied your logic it does not give correct resutls

Comment: You have to update the question with a clear example

Comment: I have added an answer to illustrate my point

Comment: @mozway Your solution only works for certain values. For example I have edited the values in the dataframe present in the question. Now if we apply your solution the correct solution should be `row 1` should give `1`, `row 2` should give `1`,  `row 3` should give `2` and `row 4` should give `2` but instead it gives 1, 0, 2, 2.